# In the axiomatic treatment of natural numbers, can we define what a natural number is?

Tags: axioms, peano-axioms, formal-systems

In his book *Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis*, Elliot Mendelson first defines a *Peano system* (p. 53). He then goes on to prove that two arbitrary Peano systems are isomorphic — they are essentially the same (p. 80). He then makes a basic existence assumption — there exists a Peano system (p. 83).

In his book *The Real Numbers and Real Analysis*, Ethan D. Bloch states Axiom 1.2.1 (Peano Postulates) (p. 3). Axiom 1.2.1 states the existence of a Peano system, namely $(\mathbb{N}, s, 1)$. Then, in Exercise 1.2.8 (p. 11), he mentions that two (arbitrary) Peano systems are isomorphic. So, I think Bloch’s approach is (partly) equivalent to Mendelson’s. (Bloch never defines what Peano systems are.)

Bloch then defines the set of *natural numbers* (Definition 1.2.2, p. 3) as "the set the existence of which is given in the Peano Postulates." It implies that the members of a Peano system are called natural numbers. (It reminds me of how we define vectors as elements of a vector space.) So, in his treatment of natural numbers, it seems that natural number isn’t a primitive notion.

On the other hand, Landau, in his book *Foundations of Analysis*, doesn’t try to define natural numbers. Instead, he takes it as an undefined term, which, I think, is how an axiomatic treatment works.

If I wanted to define what natural numbers are, would the following sequence be logically accurate?

1. State the definition of a Peano system.
2. Prove that two arbitrary Peano systems are isomorphic.
3. Assume that there exists a Peano system.
4. Define natural numbers as elements of the underlying set of that Peano system.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Paul Benecerraf's fascinating paper about [What numbers could not be](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2183530) may be of interest.

Comment: @RobArthan If someone asks what exactly a vector is, the answer would be that a vector is an element of a vector space. Now, if he asks what exactly a natural number is, could the answer be that a natural number is an element of a Peano system?

Comment: I don't think so. Did you read the paper?

Comment: Almost finished.

Comment: More or less... we have to start from our intuition about numbers and their properties: what we lear at school about even-odd, addition, multiplication, associativity and commutativity, and so on. Then someone (Dedekind, Peano) writed a simple set of axioms that are enough to prove all known facts about natural numebrs.

Comment: Then we move to a more abstract level (Landau, Mendelson) and we define an *abstarct* structure called "Peano system", that is a collection of objects and fundamental operations on them that satisfy the Peano axioms. Using suitable mathematical resources (e.g. set theory) we prove that all Peano systems are *isomorphic*, i.e. all behave the same wrt to the axioms. Thus, the natural numbers are one of those systems, but we have no way to prove that it is the only one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: surely the situation is a bit more definite than you say in your last comment. We know that there are hosts of  distinct Peano systems: At each stage of his construction of the number systems after $\Bbb{N}$, Landau has a nice statement where he throws out the earlier stage and replaces it with its image in the new stage: so he ends up with 5 different Peano systems: $\Bbb{N$} and its image in $\Bbb{Z}, $\Bbb{Q}$, $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Landau starts his treatment of natural numbers with the following. "We assume the following to be given: A set (i.e. totality) of objects called natural numbers, possessing the properties—called axioms—to be listed below." When discussing primitive notions, such as sets and membership, we don't say, "We assume that sets exist and membership makes sense, yo." Then, why is he assuming that the set of natural numbers exists? Isn't natural number a primitive notion? Can't we start stating the axioms without assuming the existence of the set of natural numbers?

Comment: "
    State the definition of a Peano system.
    Prove that two arbitrary Peano systems are isomorphic.
    Assume that there exists a Peano system.
    Define natural numbers as elements of the underlying set of that Peano system.
"  Isn't this just exactly what you said Bloch does?

Comment: @fleablood Kind of. But he doesn't talk about Peano systems at all. Axiom 1.2.1 starts with "There exists a set $\mathbb{N}$ with an element $1 ∈ \mathbb{N}$ and a
function $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that satisfy the following three properties."

Comment: I'm perplexed. How is Bloch getting around the "problem" of having primitive notions?

Answer (score 0):

> In the axiomatic treatment of natural numbers, can we define what a natural number is?

If you mean 'just writing down the usual Peano axioms in first order logic and working from there *with just them, nothing more*', then everything is a natural number already (well, the objects at least, not the functions)

If you mean 'working in a strong set theory like ZF(C), and proving some object exist with so and so properties', that's no longer an axiomatic treatment, I'd say, but a 'genetic' one